# Connect-AzureRmAccount : Unable to find an entry point named 'GetPerAdapterInfo' in DLL 'iphlpapi.dll'

Tags: azure, powershell, automation, cloud

Simply, I'm running `Connect-AzureRmAccount` using `runbook` automation in Azure, it gives me the error below:

> Unable to find an entry point named 'GetPerAdapterInfo' in DLL
>   'iphlpapi.dll'.

I already imported the Azureprofile module and I can not figure out what is the issue.

Comment: When you use the Runbook, you are already in an exact subscription of the tenant with an account. So just run your script without connecting the account.

Comment: what? since when?

Comment: @Charles Xu, I imported a new module called Azure Resource Graph, you can find it in the following URL : (https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AzureRM.ResourceGraph/0.1.1-preview) , I'm trying now to run a simple command to count resources I have "Search-AzureRmGraph -Query "summarize count()", it gives me the following error "Search-AzureRmGraph : Run Connect-AzureRmAccount to login. At line:1 char:1for that reason I was trying to run the connect command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to connect to the Azure account with the PowerShell command `Connect-AzureRmAccount` in your Runbook, then it is really unnecessary. Just as I said in the comment, when you use the Runbook, you are already in an exact subscription of the tenant with an account. So just run your script without connecting the account.

If you really want to connect with the PowerShell, you can use the service principal like this:

```
Disable-AzureRmContextAutosave –Scope Process

$Conn = Get-AutomationConnection -Name AzureRunAsConnection
Connect-AzureRmAccount -ServicePrincipal -Tenant $Conn.TenantID -ApplicationID $Conn.ApplicationID -CertificateThumbprint $Conn.CertificateThumbprint
```

But I really suggest you can just run the PowerShell script in your Runbook directly.

**Update**

When you create the Runbook, there will be a connection for you to run the PowerShell script. Or you can create the connection as your requirement. See [Connection assets in Azure Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-connections). You could just use the default connection use the code like this:

```
$connectionName = "AzureRunAsConnection"
try
{
    # Get the connection "AzureRunAsConnection "
    $servicePrincipalConnection=Get-AutomationConnection -Name $connectionName         

    "Logging in to Azure..."
    Add-AzureRmAccount `
        -ServicePrincipal `
        -TenantId $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantId `
        -ApplicationId $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId `
        -CertificateThumbprint $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint 
}
catch {
    if (!$servicePrincipalConnection)
    {
        $ErrorMessage = "Connection $connectionName not found."
        throw $ErrorMessage
    } else{
        Write-Error -Message $_.Exception
        throw $_.Exception
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Charles, I imported a new module called Azure Resource Graph, you can find it in the following URL : https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AzureRM.ResourceGraph/0.1.1-preview , I'm trying now to run a simple command to count resources I have "Search-AzureRmGraph -Query "summarize count()", it gives me the following error "Search-AzureRmGraph : Run Connect-AzureRmAccount to login.
At line:1 char:1for that reason I was trying to run the connect command.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, in my case I was trying to simply use the Azure Cmdlet Get-AzVm.

I previously used code similar to what Charles posted above, the problem is that doesn't work with the Az Cmdlets as you can't use both the AzureRM and the new Azure modules at the same time.

I replaced all of that with the following and now it works:

```
Disable-AzContextAutosave –Scope Process
$Conn = Get-AutomationConnection -Name AzureRunAsConnection
Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -Tenant $Conn.TenantID `
-ApplicationId $Conn.ApplicationID -CertificateThumbprint $Conn.CertificateThumbprint
$AzureContext = Select-AzSubscription -SubscriptionId $Conn.SubscriptionID
```

I found this in the following article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-first-runbook-textual