# Azure PowerShell Workflow / Identity Problems / Automation

Tags: azure, powershell, workflow, identity, azure-automation

I am facing a problem with Identity in Automation Account - when I run the following code

The error I am facing is:

> You must call the Connect-AzureAD cmdlet before calling any other cmdlets.

[image]

Scriptblock :

```
workflow test
{
    Param
(
  [Parameter(Mandatory= $True)]
  [String] $GroupName,
  [Parameter(Mandatory= $True)]
  [String] $DestinationEmailAddress
)

# log AccountId
$UserManagedIdentityAccountId = "XYZ"
Disable-AzContextAutosave -Scope Process
$AzureContext = (Connect-AzAccount -Identity -AccountId $UserManagedIdentityAccountId).context
$AzureContext = Set-AzContext -SubscriptionName $AzureContext.Subscription -DefaultProfile $AzureContext
# log AccountId 

$groups = Get-AzureADGroup  -SearchString  $GroupName

$Exp = foreach($group in $groups){
     $GroupId = $group.ObjectId
     $GroupName = $group.DisplayName
     Get-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $GroupId | Select-Object -Property @{Name = 'GroupName'; Expression= {$GroupName}}, DisplayName, UserPrincipalName, usertype
 }

Write-Output $Exp 

Write-Output $GroupName
Write-Output $DestinationEmailAddress

}
```

Comment: What happens if you put ```Connect-AzureAD``` after ```# log AccountId```

Comment: The same response from the automation account:  You must call the Connect-AzureAD cmdlet before calling any other cmdlets.

Comment: Before running the `Get-AzureADGroup`  commands we need to login to Azure AD module by using `Connect-AzureAD` command

Comment: WoW ! Guys - it helps ! now I am facing something else...

One or more errors occurred.: Unable to find an entry point named 'GetPerAdapterInfo' in DLL 'iphlpapi.dll'.
One or more errors occurred.
Unable to find an entry point named 'GetPerAdapterInfo' in DLL 'iphlpapi.dll'.
One or more errors occurred.: Unable to find an entry point named 'GetPerAdapterInfo' in DLL 'iphlpapi.dll'.
You must call the Connect-AzureAD cmdlet before calling any other cmdlets.

Comment: I have a fund, but it is associated with RUNAS CONNECTION, and I need a resolution of Acc ID.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54272880/connect-azurermaccount-unable-to-find-an-entry-point-named-getperadapterinfo

Answer (score 0):

> You must call the Connect-AzureAD cmdlet before calling any other cmdlets.

As per this [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/connect-azuread?view=azureadps-2.0),to run and Authenticate any Azure AD Commands we need to first connect to authenticated account by using `Connect-AzureAD` command

- Every time you start a new session ,the Powershell asks you to authenticate and connect to the account

> One or more errors occurred.: Unable to find an entry point named 'GetPerAdapterInfo' in DLL 'iphlpapi.dll'.

Please check this [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60143334) that fix the above error

Comment: Hello, what if the modules are up-to-date?  end the error still looks like : 
Suspended
One or more errors occurred.: Unable to find an entry point named 'GetPerAdapterInfo' in DLL 'iphlpapi.dll'. (One or more errors occurred. (Unable to find an entry point named 'GetPerAdapterInfo' in DLL 'iphlpapi.dll'.))